# how to revert previous commits from a particular date on github

Tags: git, github

how do I revert previous commits from a particular date on GitHub?
For example, I want to revert my previous commits from 1st June to date. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Find those commits and say `git revert` about them. What's the hard part?

Comment: perhaps `git reset --hard commitID` with `commitID` the state you want to come back.

Comment: @Ôrel There are a lot of commits from that date till now and I don't want to go through the hassle of identifying the IDs one by one. I just wanna revert in one go. Is there any way better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the commits before a given date with `--since`

```
git log --since 2023-06-01 -n1 --merges --format=format:%H
```

- `-n1` to get only one
- `--merges` to not get merge
- `--format` to get the sha

then reset to it

```
git reset --hard `git log --since 2023-06-01 -n1 --merges --format=format:%H`
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the exact thing I needed.